# label not inline for input in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, label

I am using Bootstrap 4 and Vue.js for populate an input form, but I can't figure out how to make the **label be in line, and before, with the input type file.**

```
<div v-for="problem in problems">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form method="POST" action="/submission" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group">
                <!-- sending the student information -->
                <input type="text" name="courseNumber" :value="courseIdSelected" style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" name="assignmentNumber" :value="assignmentSelected.id" style="display: none;">
                
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label :for="problem.name">Code submissions {{ problem.name }}</label>
                    <input type="file" name="document" :id="problem.name" class="form-control-file"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
            
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there some **solution by just using some Bootstrap class**, or I would need to change the style (CSS) to make it show the label in the same line as the input.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the issue (html label is not inline with the input)]

Comment: Does this help? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sample for inline from bs4:

```
  <div class="form-group row"> 
    <label :for="problem.name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Code submissions {{ problem.name }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
<input type="file" name="document" :id="problem.name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the input inside the label it would help you solving your problem

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form method="POST" action="/submission" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group">
                <!-- sending the student information -->
                <input type="text" name="courseNumber" :value="courseIdSelected" style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" name="assignmentNumber" :value="assignmentSelected.id" style="display: none;">
                
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label :for="problem.name">
                    <input type="file" name="document" id="problem.name" class="form-control-file"/>
                    Code submissions {{ problem.name }}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
            
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

wrapping your `input` tag inside a `div` will solve your issue

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div v-for="problem in problems">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <form method="POST" action="/submission" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group">
        <!-- sending the student information -->
        <input type="text" name="courseNumber" :value="courseIdSelected" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" name="assignmentNumber" :value="assignmentSelected.id" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">

          <label :for="problem.name">Code submissions {{ problem.name }}</label>

          <!-- wrapping your input tag inside a div -->
          <div>
            <input type="file" name="document" :id="problem.name" class="form-control-file" />
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```